# How to stub Mongoose model constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sinon

I'm trying to use Sinon.js to stub the model constructor of my `Student` Mongoose model.

```
var Student = require('../models/student');

var student = new Student({ name: 'test student' }); // I want to stub this constructor
```

Looking at the Mongoose source code, [Model](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L58) inherits its prototype from [Document](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js#L97), which calls the [`Document`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js#L39) function, so this is what I tried in order to stub the constructor. However, my stub never gets called.

```
sinon.stub(Student.prototype__proto__, 'constructor', () => {
  console.log('This does not work!');
  return { name: 'test student' };
});

createStudent(); // Doesn't print anything
```

Thank you for any insight.

EDIT:
I can't directly set `Student()` as a stub, because I also stub `Student.find()` in another test. So my question is essentially "how do I stub `Student()` and `Student.find()` at the same time?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It surely can be done only with sinon, but that will be very dependant on the way the lib works, and will not feel safe and maintainable.

For dependancies that are hard to mock directly, you should take a look at [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) or [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) (I use rewire, but you may want to have a choice) to do "monkey patching".

You will use `rewire` like `require`, but it has some sugar.
Example :

```
var rewire = require("rewire");
var myCodeToTest = rewire("../path/to/my/code");

//Will make 'var Student' a sinon stub.
myCodeToTest.__set__('Student', sinon.stub().returns({ name: 'test'}));

//Execute code
myCodeToTest(); // or myCodeToTest.myFunction() etc..

//assert
expect...
```

[EDIT]

> "how do I stub Student() and Student.find() at the same time?"

```
//Will make 'var Student' a sinon stub.
var findStub = sinon.stub().returns({});
var studentStub = sinon.stub().returns({find: findStub});
myCodeToTest.__set__('Student', studentStub);
```